# How to share a tethered iPhone internet connection with virtualbox guest os (Win XP)

Tags: 12.04, networking, virtualbox

I mostly connect to the internet via a USB iPhone tethered connection (MyWi app). I have just installed Windows XP guest OS via Virtualbox. How do I connect the guest OS to the internet via my tethered iPhone connection? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to use a bridge network.

- Simply select `Network` tab under the guest OS `Settings`.
- Select `Adapter 1` tab and check the `Enable Network Adapter` box
- Select `Bridge Adapter` under `Attached to:`
- Finally under `Name` select the preferred method of connection. For example my wired tethered internet connection is labelled `eth1`

[image: Guest OS XP connecting to the internet via iPhone tethering]